# how can i show active page in Django pagination

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, django

am using django 2.0 and am trying to make this blog, the issue is that once i click the next page the active bar in the pagination section  dont change mean from 1 to 2 see pic [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIccl.jpg)

i don't know where is the mistake

here is the views.py

```html
def post_list(request):
    object_list=Post.objects.filter(status='Published').order_by("-created")
    pages = pagination(request,object_list,3)
    context={
        'items':pages[0],
        'page_range':pages[1],
    }
    return render(request,"blog.html",context)
```

pagination function

```html
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator

def pagination(request,data,num=10):
    paginator = Paginator(data,num) # Show 5 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page',5)
    try:
        items=paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        items=paginator.page(5)
    except EmptyPage:
        items=paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    index=items.number=1
    max_index=len(paginator.page_range)
    start_index=index - 5 if index >= 5 else 0
    end_index=index + 5 if index <= max_index - 5 else max_index
    page_range=paginator.page_range[start_index:end_index]
    return items, page_range
```

and pagination.html

```html
<nav>
{% if items.has_other_pages %}
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if items.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ items.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in page_range %}
      {% if items.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if items.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ items.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
  </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
  </nav>
```

blog.html

```html
{% for obj in items %}
    {% if obj.status == 'Published' %}
      <article>
        <img src="{{obj.thumb.url}}" alt="" />
        <div class="post-content">
          <h2>{{obj.title}}</h2>
            {{obj.created}}  Author {{obj.user}} <h4><a href="{% url 'category_detail' slug=obj.Category.slug %}">{{obj.Category}}</a></h4>
            <hr/>
            <p>{{obj.body}}</p>
    <a class="mtr-btn button-navy ripple" href= "{% url 'post_detail' obj.slug %}">Continue reading →</a><br>
    </div>
    </article>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% include 'pagination.html' %}
</div>
```

Comment: What's this line `index=items.number=1` doing? You're setting `items.number` to 1?

Comment: yes am setting the items number to 1 is incorrect or

Comment: Of course that’s incorrect, that’s the active page number. And in your template you check if that’s == I for the active page.

Comment: not sure if i got you

Comment: Look at your code: `items` is a `Page` object of your paginator. Remove `= 1` as `items.number` should be the actual page number.

Comment: i have removed it still page 2 is not active

Comment: that's not possible. what does `print(page_range)` and `print(items.number)` give you?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `= 1` from the line `index = items.number = 1`